# Numpy specify order of subarrays with custom dtype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dtype

Let's say I have a dtype that contains a subarray:

```
dt = np.dtype([('a', float), ('b', float, (2, 3)), ('c', float)])
```

I can use this to load an array from a file:

```
tmp = np.array([(1.0, np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3), 2.0), (2.0, np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3), 3.0)], dtype=dt)
tmp.tofile('tmp.bin')

arr = np.fromfile('tmp.bin', dtype=dt)
```

So far so good. `arr` looks like this:

```
array([(1., [[0., 1., 2.], [3., 4., 5.]], 2.),
       (2., [[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]], 3.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8', (2, 3)), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Is there a way to tell `np.fromfile` to load `arr['b']` in Fortran order so that I get the following?

```
array([(1., [[0., 3., 1.], [4., 2., 5.]], 2.),
       (2., [[1., 4., 2.], [5., 3., 6.]], 3.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8', (2, 3)), ('c', '<f8')])
```

If I can't load the array directly with stride metadata specified up front, is there an alternative to doing

```
arr['b'] = arr['b'].T.reshape(arr['b'].shape)
```

The problem with this transpose is that it will create a temp array and copy the data instead of just adjusting the strides.

Comment: I was going to quip 'read the docs', but then saw your name.  You don't ask naive things.  I think tofile just writes the databuffer.  `np.save` without the header. `fromfile` is also simple. load the data and assign the dtype.  The databuffer should be identical after loading.

Comment: @hpaulj. I am effectively asking if it's possible to use the dtype or some other mechanism to adjust the strides of an array after reading it out. For example if I read an array floats as `arr = np.fromfile('blah', dtype=float).reshape(-1, 3, 3)`, I could transpose the matrices in it with something simple like `arr = arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)` or `arr.strides = [arr.strides[0], arr.strides[2], arr.strides[1]]`. But I can't seem to find a way to do it for a matrix embedded among other cruft in a custom dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj. The last line is one way to do it, but it involves copying data, which I am hoping is unnecessary.

Comment: I've never looked at strides in compound dtypes.

Comment: @hpaulj. Me neither. Never had the need to until something came up today.

Comment: Assigning `np.arange(6).reshape(3,2).T` to a record of `tmp`, rearranges the values, but doesn't change `tmp['b'].strides`.  The values are copied to the `tmp` databuffer, but none of the `strides` information.

Comment: @hpaulj. Correct, which is what I would like to try to avoid.

Comment: Each record of your array is stored as a contiguous block of 64 bytes.  `tmp[0]` is a `numpy.dtype[void]` object.  You could `view` `tmp` with `dt2 = np.dtype([('a', float), ('b', float, (3,2)), ('c', float)])`, but that just reshapes the 'b' elements, not transposes them.

Comment: @hpaulj. Somewhere in viewing with a dtype containing an array, there is an implicit stride. It bugs me that I haven't figured out where, or how to make it explicit.

Comment: `tmp['b'].transpose(0,2,1)` can change order in the records

Comment: @hpaulj. Correct, which is the end goal.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm beginning to realize that strides only come into play when you make an array view of something. The "right" answer might just be to modify the view that is `arr['b']` every time, e.g. `v = arr['b']; v.strides = v.strides[:arr.ndim] + v.strides[-1:arr.ndim-1:-1]`

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace the shortcut that is `arr['b']` with the equivalent `np.ndarray(...)` expression using the elements of `arr.dtype`. I could really go crazy and write an array subclass that uses something like [`haggis.npy_util.iterate_dtype`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.npy_util.iterate_dtype)

Comment: @hpaulj. If you, or one of the other gurus, don't come up with an alternative, I'll tentatively post my comments in a day or so.